# Django query is not reaching to the the page

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls

I want to add a contact html page in my existing project. I put the html page in template where homepage is already residing. Now I have added a url for contact in project level directory which directing the query to app level url. This app level has a contact function in views. I have setup app level url as well but contact link isnt responding. In debug its showing a 200 ok status. Could somebody can point out to me what wrong i am doing???
This is project level url file

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('articles.urls')),
    path('contact', include('articles.urls')),
]
```

this is app level url file

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.articles, name='articles'),
    path('', views.contact, name='contact'),
]
```

this is view function in which one function is returning article page but other one not responding

```
def articles(request):
    return render(request, 'articles/home.html')

def contact(request):
    return render(request, 'articles/contact.html')
```

Comment: You made two paths with the same pattern, hence if you visit `/`, it will fire the `articles` view, not the `contact` view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In debug its showing a 200 ok status. Could somebody can point out to me what wrong i am doing?

You defined two paths with an empty string. They fire `articles` and `contact` respectively. Since `articles` is specified first, if you visit the "home page", it will fire the `articles` view.

Each HTTP request will only fire *one* view, and that view will produce an HTTP response. If you thus want to add something to contact somebody, then you should alter the `articles` view, or work with another path that will trigger the `contact` view.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot give 2 path for 2 views so you need you change your url path, you can do something like below if you have both article and contact view on `articles` **app**'s `views.py` file.

project level **urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('articles.urls')),
]
```

app level **urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('article/', views.articles, name='articles'),
    path('contact/', views.contact, name='contact'),
]
```

Now you to use `127.0.0.1:800/article/` for article view and `127.0.0.1:800/contact/` for contact view.